# Formatted address not showing in suggestions in google autocomplete address form

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, street-address, google-geolocation, usps

I have implemented a simple google autocomplete address input in my project when I type:

> 4471 Ventura Canyon

it suggests me three addresses:

1. 4471 Ventura Canyon Avenue, CA, United States
2. 4471 Ventura Canyon Drive, Katy, TX, United States
3. 4471 Ventura Canyon Court, Katy, TX, United States

The problem is it should also suggest me another address which is

> 4471 Ventura Canyon Avenue, Sherman Oaks, CA, United States

This address is actually the formatted address of **4471 Ventura Canyon Avenue, CA, United States**

I need the complete address for shipping purposes so that I can use it in [USPS](https://www.usps.com/).

You can try it here on [google's example page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform).

Comment: Are you trying to validate that an address is valid or just trying to get suggestions?  Keep in mind that this same address is valid, according to the USPS, with both of the following cities.

Van Nuys, CA  https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=1&companyName=&address1=4471+Ventura+Canyon&address2=&city=Van+Nuys&state=CA&urbanCode=&postalCode=&zip=

Sherman Oaks, CA
https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=1&companyName=&address1=4471+VENTURA+CANYON&address2=&city=Sherman+Oaks&state=CA&urbanCode=&postalCode=&zip=

Comment: I'm trying to get the suggestions of addresses with city name in it so that USPS can verify it. have a look on these screenshots [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/i0l2k3) and [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/i0l38o)

Comment: Which city names would you like to see for each address?  All of the possible city names for each address or just a few of the city names?  If only a few city names, which few would you like?  In some locations there can be more than ten acceptable city names that the US Postal Service will accept for a single address.  Consider the following city/state combinations for zipcode 10010:  NEW YORK NY MADISON SQUARE NY
MANHATTAN NY
NEW YORK CITY NY
NY NY
NY CITY NY
NYC NY     I'm happy to answer more:  support@smartystreets.com